# JPS only displays JPS

Tags: java, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am trying to analyze the memory usage of my Java application using the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It's acquire heap tool uses a combination of JPS and JMAP. For some reason, my application is not listed by JPS.

At first nothing was listed so then I thought it might be an permissions issue. I ran it in an administrator command prompt and it started to list itself, but it still not my application.

If I'm not mistaken, it should list both my application and Eclipse as it is a Java application.

This is in a Windows 7 64-bit environment.

Comment: Same problem here, any solution to this? I am not sure what "instrumented" means exactly

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `jps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) states the following:

> The  jps  tool  lists the instrumented HotSpot Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system. The tool is limited to reporting information on JVMs for which it has the access permissions.
>
> The list of JVMs produced by the jps command may be limited by the permissions granted to the principal running the command. The command will only list the JVMs  for  which  the  principle  has  access rights as determined by operating system specific access control mechanisms.

So access problems will certainly prevent processes that the user running the command does not have access to, or does not own, from being listed in the output.

Comment: Shouldn't the Windows administrator have access to any process though?